# Initialize parent class with empty constructor in initializer list?

Tags: c++

Are there any dangers in not initializing an empty constructor parent class in the child initialization list?

Example:

```
class Parent
{
  public:
    Parent(){}
    ~Parent(){}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
  public:
    Child(): Parent()
    {}
    ~Child(){}
};
```

Reason for the question: I often see code where a "Parent" class with an empty ctor is not initialized in the child ctor initialization list.

Comment: The default constructor is called implicitly if you don't explicitly call a constructor in the initialization list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `Parent` doesn't have a user-provided constructor, e.g. if it is an aggregate:

```
struct Parent
{
    int x;
    int get_value() const { return x; }
};
```

Now there's a difference (cf. [dcl.init]/(8.1)), since value-initialization of `Parent` will zero-initialize the member `x`, whereas default-initialization will not:

```
struct GoodChild : Parent { GoodChild() : Parent() {} };

struct BadChild : Parent { BadChild() {} };
```

Therefore:

```
int n = GoodChild().get_value(); // OK, n == 0

int m = BadChild().get_value();  // Undefined behaviour
```

Comment: Specifically, according to C++11 the base will be default-initialised when the initialiser is not given (`[C++11: 12.6.2/8]`), and default-initialising an aggregate does nothing useful. By contrast, including `Parent()` in the _ctor-initialiser_ will end up value-initialising its members (`[C++11: 12.6.2/7]`).

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your objection? I'd be happy to improve on unclear or missing points (or just edit it yourself).

Comment: @T.C.: That makes sense, thanks. I've edited the post to reflect that. (Cleaning up the comments.)